# JavaScript Replace Method for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Can anyone please tell me how I can use the replace method to replace a character if it occures in more than one textbox without having to write separate function for each textbox.

The code below is the basic way to use the replace method but it only allows for one textbox.

I'm sure I need a loop in there but I'm not sure how to use that without affecting the replace method.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

    <script language="javascript">
        function stringReplace(form) {
            var replaceStr = form.textfield1.value
            var pattern = /\'/g;
            form.textfield1.value = replaceStr.replace(pattern, "''");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="JStest_redirect.asp">
        <p>fname:
            <input type="text" name="textfield1" size="20">
        </p>
        <p>lname:
            <input type="text" name="textfield2" size="20">
        </p>
        <p>
            <input onclick="return stringReplace(form)" type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
        </p>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure of your pattern ? What are you really trying to do ? why ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
function stringReplace(form) {
    var $inputs = $(form).find('input:text');
    var pattern = /\'/g;
    $inputs.each(function () {
        this.value = this.value.replace(pattern, "''");
    });
    return false;  // Prevent the form from being submitted
}
```

This would find all the input type text within the form and replace their values.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to do it without jquery, you can use the [getElementsByTagName()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp) method.

```
function stringReplace(form) {

    var pattern = /\'/g;
    var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input");

    var input;
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        input = inputs[i];
        if (input.type = 'text') {
            var replaceStr = input.value;
            input.value = replaceStr.replace(pattern, "''");

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want

```
function stringReplace(form) {
   $('input[type=text]').val(function(_, v) {
      return v.replace(/\'/g, "''");
   });
   return false;
}
```

I added a `return false` at the end to prevent the form to be submitted on click. You probably want to have a separate button in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that fisrt you have to take all the values

```
 function GetValue(){
var Contain = "";
$("#form1 :text").each(function(){
 //add replace code here
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add `onchange` function to all of you text input

```
function stringReplace(textField) {
            var replaceStr = this.value
            var pattern = /\'/g;
            this.value = replaceStr.replace(pattern, "''");
        }
```

and than you add

```
<input type="text" name="textfield1" size="20" onchange="stringReplace(this);">
```